# Spark agg to collect a single list for multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

Here is my current code:

```
pipe_exec_df_final_grouped = pipe_exec_df_final.groupBy("application_id").agg(collect_list("table_name").alias("tables"))
```

However, in my collected list, I would like multiple column values, so the aggregated column would be an array of arrays. Currently the result look like this:

```
1|[a,b,c,d]
2|[e,f,g,h]
```

However, I would also like to keep another column attached to the aggragation (lets call it 'status' column name).  So my new output would be:

```
1|[[a,pass],[b,fail],[c,fail],[d,pass]]
...
```

I tried `collect_list("table_name, status")`  however `collect_list` only takes one column name.  How can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 14):

Use `array` to collect columns into an array column first, then apply `collect_list`:

```
df.groupBy(...).agg(collect_list(array("table_name", "status")))
```